# Nonsensical TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this simple code:

```
...
for (var w:Number=0; w < MAX_w; w++){

   for (var k:Number=0; k < MAX_k; k++){

      trace("test01");

      if(w != k){
         trace("test02");
         ///do sth...
      }
   }
}
...
```

And output is:

```
...
test01 
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at NS_fla::MainTimeline/vzdalenosti_bodu()
at NS_fla::MainTimeline/hlaska_zmacknul_sem()
...
```

Please suspects anybody what cause this problem?

Thx for answer.

Comment: At first, `trace(MAX_w, MAX_k)` before this nested loop. If either is undefined, this is your error's cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it only traces "test01" once, then the problem would not be from whatever is in the if(w!=k) scope, because the first time w=k=0. If your MAX_w and MAX_k are 0 then the problem would be coming from after the loop. In any case, the problem is not with w or k, and I think more code is needed in order to solve this issue.
BTW: Why Number and not int?

Comment: Yes the cause problem was under of this if. I have undeclared Array :) Sorry for waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

According to Run-time errors reference:

This error can occur if you are trying to access a property of an object that does not exist. 
For example:

```
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.a = "foo";
trace(obj.b.prop);
```

You can also see this error because of a mispelling, for example in the following, where mc represents a MovieClip object on the display list, and the stage property is misspelled with a capital S (it should be stage):

```
trace(mc.Stage.quality);
```

All errors are here - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/runtimeErrors.html